# SELECT LIKE with binary column returns no results when hex is too long for a specific uuid

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a UUID column (code below, shortened for demo sake).  When I was demoing my application yesterday, I had an issue where the an item I had created in the table with a uuid4 value would not pull up when searching for the full uuid; but eventually pulled up when I tried shortening the UUID I was searching for.  When I created a second item with a new uuid4, I was able to search for that one just fine.

I'm not sure what the issue might be nor how to even debug it on the MySQL side.  'HEX'ing the column and doing a string comparison is not an option as I need to be able to use the index on the uuid column.

Since using UUID's is the primary and only method of looking items up (business requirements dictate not using the integer PK), I need to determine a solution that works 100% of the time.

```
CREATE TABLE `ItemTable` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uuid` (`uuid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `ItemTable` (`uuid`)
VALUES (UNHEX('0BFADD4EEFC14C05A7CA83245C37EEB7'));

INSERT INTO `ItemTable` (`uuid`)
VALUES (UNHEX('6C52ACF3864E49BCBC4E7A7B2CBB90C5'));

SELECT * FROM `ItemTable` where uuid LIKE CONCAT(UNHEX('0BFADD4EEFC14C05A7CA83245C37EEB7'), '%'); -- No Results

SELECT * FROM `ItemTable` where uuid LIKE CONCAT(UNHEX('0BFADD4EEFC14C05A7CA83245C37EE'), '%'); -- No Results

SELECT * FROM `ItemTable` where uuid LIKE CONCAT(UNHEX('0BFADD4EEFC14C05A7CA83245C37'), '%'); -- No Results

SELECT * FROM `ItemTable` where uuid LIKE CONCAT(UNHEX('0BFADD4EEFC14C05A7CA83245C'), '%'); -- No Results

SELECT * FROM `ItemTable` where uuid LIKE CONCAT(UNHEX('0BFADD4EEFC14C05A7CA8324'), '%'); -- Theres the first one!!

SELECT * FROM `ItemTable` where uuid LIKE CONCAT(UNHEX('6C52ACF3864E49BCBC4E7A7B2CBB90C5'), '%'); -- Works right off the bat with the full UUID.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a few notes to aid you in debugging this.  Somewhere below may be an "answer" to a "question" you might have had, but didn't ask. (I'm assuming that you meant to ask a question, and weren't just giving a status report.)

**`x'5C'`** evaluates to a backslash character **`'\'`**. And the backslash is the standard character that MySQL uses for *escape sequences*.

As an example, **`'\n'`** is *not* interpreted as two separate characters (a backslash and an n). It's evaluated as a *single* newline character. To get a backslash character returned, we normally have to escape the backslash itself with another backslash. As a demonstration, consider:

```
SELECT HEX('\n')    --> '0A'
SELECT HEX('\\n')   --> '5C6E'
```

The `UNHEX` function returns a binary string. Before MySQL 5.5, the `CONCAT` function returned a binary string, but with later versions, it produces a nonbinary string. I'd expect the `LIKE` comparison would work with `BINARY` datatype (that's my expectation, but I haven't tested that.)

But consider this: the effect of "doubling up" the backslash characters...

```
SELECT v
     , v LIKE UNHEX('335C37')
     , v LIKE UNHEX('335C5C37')
     , v LIKE REPLACE(UNHEX('335C37'),'\\','\\\\')
  FROM ( 
         SELECT CAST(UNHEX('335C37') AS BINARY) AS v 
       ) t
```

Returns:

```
v     v LIKE UNHEX('335C37')  v LIKE UNHEX('335C5C37')  v LIKE REPLACE(UNHEX('335C37'),'\\','\\\\')
----  ----------------------  ------------------------  -------------------------------------------
3\7                        0                         1                                            1
```

---

NOTE: you would perform the REPLACE function *after* the UNHEX operation, a sequence of `5C` could actually be from `'35C4'`. Doing the replacement on the hex digits (without assuring the byte boundary) would introduce a spurious `C5` character

**DON'T DO THIS:**

```
UNHEX(REPLACE('35C4','5C','5C5C'))   -->  x'35C5C4'  (wrong!)
```

**DO THIS:**

```
REPLACE(UNHEX('35C4'),'\\','\\\\')   --> x'35C4'     (right!)
```

---

Are there characters other than the backslash that present potential issues?

Consider `x'5F'`, and `x'25'`, which are the underscore and percent characters, respectively. Those have special meanings in a string on the right side of a `LIKE` operator. (Likely, you'll want to escape those as well.

Escape the backslashes first, then the other characters. I'm thinking you are going to need an expression like this:

```
 REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( x ,'\\','\\\\'),'_','\\_'),'%','\\%')
```

And do that before you concatenate on the final `'%'` character.

Comment: Sorry, my question, more or less, is why is this happening, and what I can I adjust or change to solve the problem?

What you said makes some sense, I'll play with this and see what I can come up with.  Thanks

Comment: @MattZuba: dollars to donuts in your specific example, it's the backslash character; I've appended to my answer to give more direction. If you're messing with BINARY and UNHEX, it's important you have an understanding of what's going on. The next big question: are there characters other than the x'5C' backslash that are also going to give a problem...  HINT: consider what will happen with other characters, such as `x'5F'`, and `x'25'` (those are the underscore and percent characters, respectively... which have special meaning in the string on the right side of `LIKE`).

Comment: Indeed, I was just thinking of those other special SQL characters that could cause issues.  I'll need to harden my query a bit more, but what you provided gave some great insight into the issue and how I can start working towards a solution.  There would indeed be more characters that could cause issues because the uuid4 is completely random.  Thanks again for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: To "escape" the underscore and percent characters, precede them with a backslash character. And again, within a string literal, you'll need to escape the backslash with another backslash. I've appended to my answer, showing nesting of REPLACE functions. (I also usually specify **`ESCAPE '\\'`** clause following the **`LIKE`**, to make it explicit. I think backslash is the default... I don't know whether that default can be changed or will ever be different, but I protect my SQL statement, just in case.)